# Placeholder Text on a dynamic PHP Link

Tags: php

I am trying to add placeholder text into PHP code

```
$message = sprintf( __( "Welcome,<br><br><br><a href=%s%s%s>Click Here</a> to login and start using the cool website features.<br><br><br>Best Wishes", "profile-builder" ), '<a href="'.$registration_page_url.'">', $registration_page_url, '</a>.' );
```

As you can see I have tried applying the HTML method by adding:

```
<a href=%s%s%s>Click Here</a>
```

It doesn't work, it displays the link followed by 'Click here'

Comment: Now what is `__()`? A concat function? Isn't `$this . $that` easier?

Comment: Use a variable don't use that. <a href='$placeholder'>Click Here</a>.   Then assign $placeholder as a variable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

why you are repeating your sprintf assignment ?

you've added 3 place holders inside the `anchor` tag and then replaced them with 3 variables,

the issue here is that your variables will conflict with the base anchor tag

this will works fine:

```
$message = sprintf( __( "Welcome,<br><br><br><a href="%s">Click Here</a> to login and start using the cool website features.<br><br><br>Best Wishes", "profile-builder" ), $registration_page_url);
```